# Javascript not getting called inside div of ionic template hml file

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

In my ionic app from the controller I received a json string of comma separated values. I want to display the json string in a html in tabular format. The html is placed inside template directory.

I am calling a java script function from the div of html to achieve this but the js function is not getting hit. The js is included in index.html. What I am doing wrong?

Here is the sample:

the template/shop.html file:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">
<!-- Dashboard Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong">
    <ion-view view-title="Shop">
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item ng-repeat="shop in shopList">
<!--
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-50 text-center">
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                **createTable({{shop.Method}})**
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
-->
                    <div id="Method"></div>
                            <script>
                                console.log("Inside div");  **HERE IS THE CALL TO JS FUNCTION** 
                                **createTable({{shop.Method}});**
                            </script>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</ion-tab>
<!-- Chats Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Chats" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes">
    <ion-view view-title="Shop">
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item ng-repeat="shop in shopList">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-50 text-center">
                            {{shop.Offers}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ion-item>
             </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</ion-tab>
```

And here is my smaple JS function placed in utility.js

```
//function createTable($scope, method){
function createTable(Method){
//    var tar=document.getElementById(Method);
//    $scope.shopMethod = [];
      var table=document.createElement('TABLE');
      table.border='1';
      var tbdy=document.createElement('TBODY');
      table.appendChild(tbdy);          
      for (var j=0;j<4;j++){
                       var tr=document.createElement('TR');
                       tbdy.appendChild(tr);
                       for (var k=0;k<2;k++){
                        var td=document.createElement('TD');
                        td.width='100';
                        if(k==0) td.innerHTML="School" +(j+1);
                        else    td.innerHTML="Percent" +(j+1);                                            
                        tr.appendChild(td);
                       }
              }
     //tar.appendChild(table);

//                            <div class="row">
//                            <div class="col col-50 text-center">
//                                {{shop.Method}}
//                            </div>
//                        </div>
//                            </div>
// $scope.shopMethod.push(table);
     console.log(table);
//document.getElementById(Method).innerHTML="Hello"
}
```

Comment: And where in your html file is the js file included?

Comment: have you tried with angular function instead of JS function?

Comment: The js is included in index.html                                                                    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/utility.js"></script>

Comment: Didn't try angular function. Will explore.